# MongoDB $substr from index to index

Tags: string, mongodb, substr, operations

The data is like "abc abc abc (xyz) efg efg".

I am trying to extract the xyz from the string.

Trying to do this in the $project section:

```
 $project:   {
        bracketextract : { $substr: [ "$title",{ $indexOfCP: [ "$title", "(" ]}, { $indexOfCP: [ "$title", ")" ]} - { $indexOfCP: [ "$title", "(" ]} ]}, 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/index.html) to the length (you're using `-` currently) and there should be `1` [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/index.html)-ed to the starting point

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project:   {
            bracketextract : { $substr: [ "$title", { $add: [ { $indexOfCP: [ "$title", "(" ]}, 1 ] } , { $subtract: [ { $indexOfCP: [ "$title", ")" ]}, { $add: [ { $indexOfCP: [ "$title", "(" ]}, 1 ] } ] } ]}, 
        }
    }
])
```

More readable way using [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html):

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            bracketextract: { 
                $let: {
                    vars: { 
                        start: { $add: [ { $indexOfCP: [ "$title", "(" ] }, 1 ] }, 
                        end: { $indexOfCP: [ "$title", ")" ] }
                    },
                    in: { $substr: [ "$title", "$$start", { $subtract: [ "$$end", "$$start" ] } ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```